# how to mute an entryphone

Tags: doorbell

I have this old entryphone and need to find a way to mute it. And if possible, connect it to a switch, so I can easily mute and unmute it. Can anybody help, please?

I have to mute it, because from time to time someone rings at 4am in the morning. I don't know whether is just to get into the building or to me. It's an old 5901 model.

More info here https://interfoni.rs/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Entryphone-5901-interfonska-slusalica_-sema-prikljucaka-1.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're gonna have to give us a little more here.  Are there other people living in the building?  If so, do they each have an entryphone in their unit?  Does your unit ring when your entryphone is off the hook?

Comment: Assuming you want to disable the one in your unit only, the easy button is to find the wires to the ringer, and insert a switch into the circuit.  You can probably get all fancy and design some sort of timer or something, but a switch is simple enough to turn off when you go to sleep and turn on when you wake.

Comment: can't you just take it off the hook before bed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Prevent it ringing**

I'm assuming you are comfortable with simple wiring...

According to the schematic: remove the white wire (2nd row from the bottom all the way on the left) Run this to a switch, and then from the other side of the switch back that terminal. That terminal is what causes it to ring.

USE CAUTION AS IT SOUNDS LIKE YOU'RE IN A MULTI TENANT BUILDING AND CANNOT ISOLATE POWER. TYPICALLY THESE DEVICES USE LOW DC VOLTAGE, BUT AGAIN, IT SOUNDS LIKE YOU CANNOT ISOLATE POWER.

I'd do it, but I don't know your skill set so am just warning you will be working energized.

Comment: @rohit-gupta and 
jsteffler thank you. I"ll try that with care :) –

Comment: @rohit-gupta and 
jsteffler It works! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Cool, your welcome